# Onsen UI v-ons-icon not working

Tags: vue-component, onsen-ui, vue-cli, onsen-ui2

I just install new pwa onsen UI project for vue-cli using npm. All components working properly only icon components not showing icon while running app. 
Even, I uncomment from v-ons-components file v-ons-icon
still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I also wasn't seeing v-ons-icon components although everything else showed. The icons did show when in `npm run dev` but not after `npm run build` when opening the app from the built index.html file or running the app in the android emulator.

I got errors like `GET file:///Users/[username]/[appname]/www/dist/static/css/static/fonts/fa-solid-900.132e975.ttf` net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and the file it was looking for would be in the place it was looking for, just without the "css" folder.

For example, the build would point to a www/dist/static/css/static/fonts/ folder for the font files, although it had placed those files in a www/dist/static/fonts folder. ... it was assuming a "css" folder to be there that wasn't there. The build process was somehow *extracting* the fonts reference into an additional "css" folder.

Since fonts were working in `dev` but not `build`, I compared `webpack.dev.conf.js` to `webpack.prod.conf.js`.

The `webpack.prod.conf.js` file contained `extract: true` inside of `rules: utils.styleLoaders`. This "extract" setting was not contained in the `webpack.dev.conf.js` file, so **I deleted `extract: true` from `webpack.prod.conf.js` ... and then, when I ran `npm run build` again, the `v-ons-icon` components showed!**